# Google custom search with ability to search specific section

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I want to use google custom search for my wordpress setup. I need the custom search to be able to search the whole site or if a checkbox is ticked, only search within a certain category of the site.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 custom search engines- one searching your whole site and another one searching the specific categories you mentioned. Based on whether the checkbox is checked or not, you can display the appropriate search box in your page. A demo of how to select specific sites or whole domains is shown in http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/google_custom_search.php